# Same rules for multiple directories in Apache?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have 2 subdomains which use the same rules, as seen below:

```
<Directory /srv/project/sites/project.hu/htdocs/>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
    SetEnv config default,local
    Order allow,deny
    allow from 192.168.0.0/16
</Directory>

<Directory /srv/project/sites/admin.project.hu/htdocs/>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
    SetEnv config default,local
    Order allow,deny
    allow from 192.168.0.0/16
</Directory>
```

As you can see the rules are the same in both  containers.
How can I specify these rules in a single container?
At first I thought about using this:

```
<DirectoryMatch ^/srv/project/sites/(?:(?:admin\.project\.hu)|project\.hu)/htdocs/$>
 ...
</DirectoryMatch>
```

But isn't there a way to do this in a more clean way that I'm missing?

Edit:
I dislike the DirectoryMatch way, because when when I'll have more directories, the regex will grow unmaintainable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

put the rewrite rules into a separate file, eg. `rewrite.conf`, and [include](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#include) it like so

```
<Directory /srv/project/sites/project.hu/htdocs/>
  Include rewrite.conf
</Directory>

<Directory /srv/project/sites/admin.project.hu/htdocs/>
  Include rewrite.conf
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<DirectoryMatch ^/srv/project/sites/(?:admin\.)?project\.hu/htdocs/$>
```

That seems fairly clean to me...